# Compare row values of a table with column values of another table and if true say true or false

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables I need to compare row values from table 1 with column names of table 2 and if they match then need to update table 2 row values as `true` for the column names matched with row values of table 1. if they dont match then it should be updated with `false`.

Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA view to obtain column names:

```
CREATE TABLE ##temp (
    column_name nvarchar(max),
    [flag] int
)

INSERT INTO ##temp
SELECT COLUMN_NAME, 0
FROM YourDB.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS  
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'YOURTableName'

UPDATE t
SET [flag] = CASE WHEN a.ColumnToCheck IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
FROM ##temp t
LEFT JOIN anotherTable a
    ON t.column_name = a.ColumnToCheck
```

Then join to your table and update, then pivot:

```
DECLARE @columns nvarchar(max), @query nvarchar(max)

SELECT @columns =STUFF((
SELECT ','+column_names FROM ##temp FOR XML PATH('')),1,1,'')

SELECT @query='
SELECT *
FROM ##temp
PIVOT (
    MAX([flag]) for column_name in ('+@columns+'
) as pvt'

EXEC sp_executesql @query
```

Better use dynamic SQL to add all column names automatically instead of manually assigning.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps

```
UPDATE TABLE2 
SET FLAG_Column = 'TRUE'
WHERE NAME_Column IN (
    Select c.name FROM sys.columns c JOIN sys.objects o ON 
    c.object_id = o.object_id
    WHERE o.name = 'TABLE1')
```